# Installing pycosat fails on MacOS

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to install `pycosat` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/pycosat/)) in a fresh virtual environment with Python 3.9 on my Macbook with MacOS Monterey 12.1. When doing so, I get the following error. The c files should be included in the package. Is there something I am missing here?

```
(solvers) ➜  solvers git:(main) ✗ pip install pycosat==0.6.3
Collecting pycosat==0.6.3
  Using cached pycosat-0.6.3.zip (66 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycosat
  Building wheel for pycosat (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      copying test_pycosat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c pycosat.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/pycosat.o
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/md/qh4j0z1s63s5c6bdwmbdqfmw0000gn/T/pip-install-bps5u3s4/pycosat_c071f69418a64b02ba0c3adba027c45c/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
          self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 117, in _compile
          self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] +
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py", line 917, in spawn
          spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py", line 56, in spawn
          proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env)
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1739, in _execute_child
          env_list.append(k + b'=' + os.fsencode(v))
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 810, in fsencode
          filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycosat
  Running setup.py clean for pycosat
Failed to build pycosat
Installing collected packages: pycosat
  Running setup.py install for pycosat ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycosat did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [65 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      copying test_pycosat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c pycosat.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/pycosat.o
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/md/qh4j0z1s63s5c6bdwmbdqfmw0000gn/T/pip-install-bps5u3s4/pycosat_c071f69418a64b02ba0c3adba027c45c/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 670, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
          self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 117, in _compile
          self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] +
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py", line 917, in spawn
          spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
        File "/Users/erwin/.virtualenvs/solvers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py", line 56, in spawn
          proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env)
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1739, in _execute_child
          env_list.append(k + b'=' + os.fsencode(v))
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 810, in fsencode
          filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycosat

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 1):

The package seems to support Python up to version 3.6. When installing it in a fresh virtual env with Python 3.6.15, I can install the package without a problem.